# What is the "SBP" distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology

On the [scikit-learn's documentation about an implementation of Variational Gaussian Mixture Models](https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/dp-derivation.html), several mentions of a "SBP" distribution is found:

$z_i \sim SBP(\phi)$

No introduction is done for this notation so I guess it is not a custom notation from their part. But I can't find any information on a probability distribution identified by this abbreviation. Does this mean something else ?

Thanks

Comment: It probably stands for “stick breaking process” and means that $z$ is categorical with probabilities obtained by applying stick-breaking to $\phi$ to get a probability vector.

Comment: So would it just be a funny way of refering to a dirichlet process ?

Comment: It’s referring specifically to $z$, which I haven’t seen people do before ($z$ is just categorical to me).